# Accessing a C++ Childclasses via Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, html, qt

I am writing on a small HTML5 Gui which is embedded in a QT-App.
The HTML5 GUI is connected to the QT-App using

```
SomeClass *someClass = new SomeClass;
this->webView->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myConnector", someClass());
```

Accessing methods within someClass works fine, but I cannot access methods of classes which are have an instance in someClass (neither using a getter nor accessing the pointer to the instanced clsas). All necessary methods/getters in the class/instanced class are declared as Q_INVOKEABLE.